# UITableView scrolling lags even for simple text

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, scroll

I am new in iOS Development and still learning.

I have text data in `unicode`, where each string is saved into `NSArray` elements. I already computed the `heightForRowAtIndexPath` and saved it separately in another array so as to minimize the computations later on. Each string has multiple lines to be displayed inside one `cell`.

I created a `custom cell xib` and registered as required. Everything works just fine but the problem is when i scroll, `tableView` is `laggy`. It takes a few milliseconds to settle the text and settling appears glitchy and hence the scroll is not as smooth as required as this lag is visible.

Here is the code.

This method is called in `viewDidLoad` to calculate height for rows.

```
 -(void) computeHeight 
{

    [array removeAllObjects];
    CGFloat height = 0;
    float high;

    self.customCell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:customCellIdentifier];

    for(int i = 0; i < self.gurbani.count; i++){
        self.customCell.customCellLabel.attributedText = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:self.gurbani[i] attributes:normalAttributes];
        [self.customCell.contentView layoutIfNeeded];
        height = [self.customCell.customCellLabel systemLayoutSizeFittingSize:UILayoutFittingCompressedSize].height;

        high = height+20.0;

        [array insertObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:high] atIndex:i];
    }
}
```

Also, below is shown the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method

```
-(UITableViewCell *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
// Fetch A Cell From Given TableView And Assign It To CustomCell
CustomCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:customCellIdentifier];

color = textColors[indexPath.row % 8];

// Customize And Feed The Cell Here
if(indexPath.row == 0 | indexPath.row == 1 | indexPath.row == 41 ) {
    cell.contentView.backgroundColor = color;
    cell.customCellLabel.backgroundColor = color;
    cell.customCellLabel.attributedText = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:self.gurbani[indexPath.row] attributes:titleAttributes];
    cell.customCellLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

}
else {
    cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    cell.customCellLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    cell.customCellLabel.attributedText = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:self.gurbani[indexPath.row] attributes:normalAttributes];
    cell.customCellLabel.textColor = color;
}
// Return The Completed Cell Here
return cell; }
```

Finally, in `heightForRowAtIndexPath`,

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
return [array[indexPath.row] floatValue]; }
```

Also, i have specified opaque in cell's contentView and other parts of the `tableView`.

Also guide me whether using core data could possibly increase scrolling performance. I am open for suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only problem was unicode text. It was Punjabi unicode text. I then used a custom font with rewritten text for that font and issue was fixed.

Answer (score 2):

You do not need to separately compute the heights of the cells and store it in an array. You can just compute the height of each cell in the `heightForRowAtIndexPath` method, and get rid of `computeHeight` method altogether.

Besides this, I see that you are using `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` inside `computeHeight` method which is unnecessary. The cell should be populated in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method.

So bottomline:

1) Get rid of `computeHeight` method

2) Move code for calculating cell height to `heightForRowAtIndexPath` method. Make sure that the correct height is returned for every row.

3) No need to track the instance of the current cell, so get rid of `self.customCell.` Set the text `(self.customCell.customCellLabel.attributedText)` in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method.

Comment: Even if i compute height in heightForRow method and remove the computeHeight method, this still offers no smoothness while scrolling. I used computeHeight only to save lengthy computations every time a cell needs to be drawn and its easy to return a value from stored array rather computing it ground up. And thank you for suggestion and considering this problem

Comment: You are using **self.customCell** to calculate height in your function. Try using **sizeWithFont: constrainedToSize: lineBreakMode** instead to calculate the dynamic height. Using this wouldn't make the computation intensive. Besides, it is customary to calculate the height for the shown cells than calculating the height of all the cells of a table in advance.

Comment: Ok i shall try the suggestion and see if that works.